# Do jQuery functions after elements created

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

I'm sorry for my bad english..
I did a jQuery function that when the user calls the function, it's creating an element on the page. To that elemet I did a jQuery click event and its working fine,
But if the user calls the function 3 times like this:

```
$.someFunction();
$.someFunction();
$.someFunction();
```

If the user clicks the first element, it will do 3 times whats in the click's event callback function, and if the user clicks the second element, it will do 2 times whats in the click's event callback function and if the user do it on the last one, it will do it once.
I want that when the user click every element then the callback function will happen just one time.
How can I fix that problem?

Comment: Show how this was implemented ?

Comment: You're probably binding the event based on the `class` or `name` attributes which will cause the events to get bound to each element `n` number of times because you would be getting each element with said `class` or `name` attribute and adding another `click` event to it. I would suggest giving each dynamically created element a unique `id` and binding the events that way instead.

Comment: You should show how event click handler is set inside your function or where it is set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something like:

```
$(".element").unbind("click").bind("click", function(){
    alert('a');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind the event to the created element rather than all existing elements.

```
$.somefunction = function() {
    $("<div />").text("click me!").bind("click",function(){
        alert("Hello World!");
    }).appendTo("body");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even easier: use jquery.on

```
$('.some-selector').on('click', function()

{
// do your work here
});
```

With jquery on ("live" in old versions) it will bind to any element matching that selector, regardless of when it is added to the DOM.

Comment: Your syntax for .on is not the syntax that creates a delegated event. Your code is identical to `$('.some-selector').click(function(){`